# How to reliably detect that the code is being executed from task queue or not?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

How could I reliably detect, deep in my code, whether the current invocation of the handler is being called from the Task Queue or not?

I understand that, in GAE/J, if I checked the `HttpServletRequest` object, I could check whether the [following headers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Task_Execution) are set:

- `X-AppEngine-QueueName`
- `X-AppEngine-TaskName`
- `X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount`
- `X-AppEngine-FailFast`
- `X-AppEngine-TaskETA`

Where the existence of any of those headers would indicate that the handler is being invoked by a task queue.

But say that the part of my code that need to do the detection is deep within several abstraction layers, where I could not access the `HttpServletRequest` object, is there any way where I could reliably detect if the current execution environment is being invoked from a task queue or not?

What I am hoping is that there could be something easily accessible like:

```
SystemProperty.environment.value() == Value.TaskQueue
```

analogous to the way we could check whether the code is being executed at GAE or at the dev server by using `SystemProperty.environment.value() == Value.Development`.

Comment: what stops you from checking headers within `doPost()` and passing the result to your abstracted logic, e.g. as a `fromTaskQueue` boolean?

Comment: @alex: The part that need the check is buried too deep within the layers of abstractions, and I would like to keep my architecture loosely coupled, passing variables would unfortunately make it less flexible.

Comment: The point of abstraction layers is to abstract; shouldn't you be avoiding this sort of abstraction breaking in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up checking the header of the request whether it contains `X-AppEngine-TaskName` or not, and, thanks to AlexR's suggestion, store the check result in a thread local variable.

Based on Eric Willigers comment below, turns out Google already discards `X-AppEngine-TaskName` header from external requests, protecting the app from malicious attackers that tried to fake the header, so this seems to be the safest approach so far.

Comment: If a malicious attacker tries to set the X-AppEngine-TaskName header, they won't succeed - the fraudulent header will be discarded before the request reaches your application.

Answer (score -1):

Try to examine the stack trace: `new Throwable().getStackTrace()`. This returns an array of `StackTraceElement`. You can iterate over the array and identify class+method typical for invocation from the queue.

Comment: This is a possible approach, and we could also use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` to get the stack trace without constructing a `Throwable` object. I'm looking for a more reliable approach though, if in the future Google change the invocation steps, checks using this approach might return incorrect results.

Comment: You can probably use HttpFilter that has access to HttpSession. It can extract the properties you mentioned and put some custom flag to ThreadLocal. Then you can use this value on other place of your code, where you do not have access to the HttpSession.

Comment: @AlexR: IMO this is a correct way to do it. Make it into an answer, I'll upvote.

Comment: @PeterKnego: Yes, I agree. AlexR, please make the comment an answer so I could accept it.